Unexpected grep Messages During SSH Command Execution
When attempting to execute SSH commands on remote servers using grep within a Bash script, I encounter unexpected grep messages instead of the expected command output.
error message :
The issue manifests with repeated Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]... messages during each SSH connection attempt.
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
  serverNames=$(grep -v "localhost" /etc/hosts | awk '/^[^#]/{ print $2 }')

  IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a servers <<< "$serverNames"
  read -p "type. : " cmd

 
  for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
      echo "Connecting to $server..."

      ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$server" "$cmd"

      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "Command executed successfully on $server"
      else
          echo "Failed to execute command on $server"
      fi
  done

else

  
  servers=("$@")


  read -p "type. : " cmd

    for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
    echo "Connecting to $server..."

  
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$server" "$cmd"

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Command executed successfully on $server"
    else
        echo "Failed to execute command on $server"
    fi
done

fi


It's about what you're typing when the prompt type. :  comes up (a grep command I guess?), so we'll need an example of that as well.

(On another note, once you've populated the servers array you're doing the exact same thing in both cases, so it doesn't make sense to repeat the same block of code twice, either refactor it into a function or, more simply, have the if-else block only populate servers and then execute the read etc block below the if-else block just once.)

Also please try hardcoding serverNames instead of parsing it that way from /etc/hosts and see if that changes anything.

Might be worth noting that ssh is one of the commands that continuously reads and consumes standard input  i.e. file descriptor 0 (like e.g. cat does) ... So, if your passed command reads that too, then it might not be able to get hold of that file descriptor meanwhile.

You need to quote the command when passing it to ssh.
Change it like this:
#!/bin/bash

execute_ssh_command() {
    local server="$1"
    local cmd="$2"
    echo "Connecting to $server..."
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$server" "$cmd"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Command executed successfully on $server"
    else
        echo "Failed to execute command on $server"
    fi
}

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    serverNames=$(grep -v "localhost" /etc/hosts | awk '/^[^#]/{ print $2 }')
    IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a servers <<< "$serverNames"
else
    servers=("$@")
fi

read -p "type. : " cmd

for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
    execute_ssh_command "$server" "$cmd"
done

For that type of operation, I would use Ansible or some other tool ideal for working with computer inventories; and still allows you to execute code in other languages like Python, Bash...etc.
Good luck!

@kos - You are right, I pasted the wrong code, I had my mind on a better solution.  Thanks!

No problem, but while certainly this is an improvement over OP's script, I still don't see how it would fix their issue - do you mind elaborating on that? Per OP's description, the issue is grep fails multiple times, conceivably because they're passing a grep command in the type. :  prompt that ends up failing. The script OP is using, besides the obvious repetition and the possibly janky parsing, seems kind ok otherwise. What does this do differently besides refactoring the repeated block into a function?

@kos - you're right again! I'm here scratching my head wondering if the /etc/hosts is consistent. A verification of that file would be advisable to check for common issues such as invisible characters, incorrect formatting, and invalid entries.

I don't think it's that either (I mean, I can be wrong), since they're mentioning multiple failures, it can't be the grep command used to parse /etc/hosts, as that is run just once if the script doesn't receive an argument - that's why I'm suspecting they're typing a (wrong) grep command in cmd

I mean, unless $server ends up containing something weird at the end. You may be right actually.

@kos - I think the grep command sent to the server every time is incorrect.
I am almost sure the grep that's failing is not in the code, it's in $cmd, hence the repetitions: it happens to every element of the array as it loops.

Most likely, yes. I asked OP, so far they haven't replied shrug

grep-or-sed-or-awk | grep-or-sed-or-awk is an anitpattern, see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#grep. In your code, grep -v "localhost" /etc/hosts | awk '/^[^#]/{ print $2 }' = awk '!/localhost/ && /^[^#]/{ print $2 }' /etc/hosts or, more robust as it won't print empty lines and arguably clearer, awk 'NF && !(/localhost/ || /^#/){ print $2 }' /etc/hosts
